# Is uploading images broken?

Tags: support, bug, images

I edited a post to upload an image but it's not showing. The link turns into an infinite redirect loop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xOhh.jpg
The question post is [Fusible plug blew on mini-split A/C, how to fix?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/144694/fusible-plug-blew-on-mini-split-a-c-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it's been down intermittently a few times today.

The most recent report about it on Meta Stack Exchange appears to be the Q&A [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down), where an employee notes in the comments that:

> [I don't have an update on this other than being more than a little angry with the state of things and that I'm working with Imgur to ensure they get it back online ASAP – Nick Craver♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down#comment1028021_313779)

Stay tuned for updates ...